# Cakephp Pagination Helper

Tags: json, api, cakephp, pagination

I need to implement pagination in cakephp.

I'm retrieving data from json url provided by Apple.

http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=games&limit=10&lang=en_us&country=GB&media=software&version=2

How do I implement Pagination with help of cakephp?

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html
in combination with an array datasource or some kind of special datasource that can provide the data in the cake way.
then the core classes can work with it the usual way.